# redirect the site IP address to the domain name

Tags: htaccess

I am attempting to redirect the IP address of my domain to the domain name and am running into trouble. The IP address does not redirect to the domain name listed in the redirect statement below.

The IP Address is `123.123.123.123`

My `.htaccess` looks like below

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^123\.123\.123\.123$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: When you access your site by IP address, do you actually get to your website? That is not the case for me. (In fact I get a **virus/malware warning**!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ordinarily your code should work OK. Although the `NC` (`NOCASE`) flag on a numeric value is unnecessary and should be removed.

Also note that if you are checking for an exact match (such as a complete IP address) it is usually easier to simply use the `=` (equals) operator, for example:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =123.123.123.123
```

This now matches against the plain string "123.123.123.123" (exact match), not a regular expression, so there is no need to escape the dots.

Your site also appears to be `example.com`, not `www.example.com` so you should change the substitution in the `RewriteRule` to reflect this, otherwise this will result in a second redirection.

However, the main problem in your case seems to be that you are on a *shared* host - multiple websites hosted on the same IP address (in fact, a rough estimate shows that there are over 500 websites on that IP address). Requesting your server's IP address does not return your website, so attempting to do this kind of redirection is not going to work.